# Square D HEPD80 Whole Home Surge Protector

Tags: circuit-breaker, surge-suppression

Please advise how I may add the Square D HEPD80 Whole Home Surge Protector to my existing panel.
The installation calls for an open circuit and I want to verify if I can or cannot safely add the device based on my existing configuration.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is piggybacking onto an existing breaker possible. In this case, my variable speed pool pump suffered and electrical surge and damaged the pumps circuit board which I just had replaced. My main concern is protecting the pool equipment. Curious if I could piggyback onto the 60amp circuit breaker which is strictly feeding the pool subpanel. Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure I've seen the piggyback before, but in my reading of the manual I didn't see that. In any case, it's clear that if it is on a breaker that max is 30 amps.

Comment: @LuisDeVivero  Page 3  "6. Connect the two HEPD50/ HEPD80 black wires to a maximum 30 A 120/240 V two-pole circuit breaker....NOTE: For circuit breakers having terminals identified for multiple conductors, the HEPD50/HEPD80 can be connected alongside multiple loads, however, the tripping of this circuit breaker will cause the entire electrical panel to lose surge protection." Look at the front of the breakers, they have little icons indicating two wires are allowed with your breakers. But I would replace an existing breaker with a homt220230cp.

Answer (score 4):

Surge protectors can share circuit breakers with existing circuits.

### *Some* of your breakers are marked for 2 wires per screw

(If they're copper = Cu).

[image]

So there you go.  Pick a breaker whose wires are about the same size as the surge's wires, and double-tap the breaker per its instructions and labeling.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. It

Comment: Thanks for all the input. It looks like I have a few breakers that indeed are designed for a 2-wire option.

Answer (score 3):

Your panel is full. That's a problem. There are two possible solutions here, but *long-term, you need to consider replacing with a larger panel or adding a subpanel*.

#### Direct Bus Installation

According to the [User Manual](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=User+guide&p_File_Name=NVE82551.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=NVE82551), you can do a *Direct Bus Installation* - see page 4. Basically, you connect the surge protector to the mounting screws between the main breaker and all the other breakers. This is a bit unusual and is the kind of thing that some people might say "how about we just cheat a little and try this...", but since it is actually sanctioned by the manufacturer, it is OK. But you have to (hopefully obviously) have the main breaker off when you do this and be *really* careful. Doing this bypasses some of the internal safety design that applies when you do a normal circuit breaker installation. But once it is installed, it should work just fine.

#### Lots of 1/2 Size Breakers

Well, not *lots*, but in order to get a standard double-breaker at the top, you'll have to do a bit of moving things around and have to replace some combination of 4 spaces with 2 spaces using 1/2-size breakers. See space 16 for an example. 10, 12 and 14 are the obvious targets, but you'll have to do more than that because you need 2 spaces and those 3 will only get you 1-1/2 spaces free. So that means replacing a double (2 x full spaces) with a quad (4 x 1/2 spaces) and make sure to have everything positioned correctly so that you have 240V where you need it and common trip/common shutoff where you need it.